# how to reduce Nextjs Static HTML Export Page size on disk?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am using Nextjs Static HTML Export and it's generating each page (Just HTML Code) with a size of 100kb + on disk.

Is there a way to reduce page size on disk?

Comment: Possibly, you need to revise/optimize your pages/components. I checked some HTML pages, generated by our app. They are around 10/20KB. The pages are simple, with informational content and no fancy components.

Comment: @Stefan I am using gzip for each page to reduced page size by 10X

Comment: I checked a page of our Vercel hosted site. The HTML page has a size of 32kB. The CDN compresses this file to 3.2kB using [Brotli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brotli). All other resources like JavaScript and CSS are compressed too. Perhaps you have a special use case. If not, the correct solution is server-based compression on behalf of client requests. Compression is only one piece of many in optimizing for speed. Let servers/providers do as much as possible for you.

Comment: @Stefan I want to cut storage costs of my really large site (about 10M pages), Just updated my question from reduce Page size to reduce Page size on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced page size by 10X using gzip in build. It increases build time, but result in smaller files. Add this in build command:

```
&& gzip -k -6 $(find public -type f)
```

More info on this can be [here](https://www.tzeyiing.com/posts/shrink-your-static-website-size-by-10x-with-this-simple-trick/)

Comment: In my opinion, this is the task of the CDN/Server. Delivering compressed/uncompressed content should respect clients preferences/capabilities. CDNs like Vercel do a good job on that. They offer a wide range of optimizations including caching, encryption, regions and of course [compression](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/edge-network/compression). Self-hosted solutions should offer similar possibilities.

Comment: @Stefan CDNs are good but some times you want your site to be small in size (On Disk) so you can copy, upload, host, backup, and do other things more efficiently and in cost friendly way.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using Minify HTML which will remove all the unnecessary whitespace from your code. This might decrease the size by a bit.

Comment: Nextjs do that by default